# dash and separator in jade of nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
- if ('production' === environment)
  script(src="/js/something.js")
- else
  script(src="/js/something_else.js")
```

I know in jade you can do if else but why there's a dash in front of the if and the else? I found that in someone's code.

and also the `|` that located beside the change room text, what is that for?

```
.modal-dialog.modal-lg
    .modal-content
      .modal-header.modal-header-bg
        .row
          .col-xs-3.text-white.uppercase
            h4.modal-title 
              span.img-icon
                i.glyphicon.glyphicon-refresh
              | Change Room
```

Comment: http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/ http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/ (it took me less than a minute to go through documentation) (never used jade ever)

Comment: leading hyphen ( - ) is used whenever you are writing a piece of code and a pipe | is used when you want to simply add text to element inline.

Comment: @kailashyogeshwar I got the pipe but not the hyphen. The ( - ) is not there when you see in the official documentation page : https://github.com/jadejs/jade#syntax why?

Comment: @AliceAnderson The `-` is for [unbuffered code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/). The "Syntax" shown in the README is only meant to be a minimal demonstration. You'll want to refer to the documentation on the project's site ([jade-lang.com](http://jade-lang.com)) for options and descriptions.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski does that mean `for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
  li item` has to be single line if there's no `-` in front of it? is that what buffered code means?

Comment: @AliceAnderson No, it probably won't do what you're hoping. Jade doesn't have a `for` keyword, so it interprets the line as a [`<for>` tag](http://jade-lang.com/reference/tags/) followed by [text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/). It uses [the `each` keyword](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/) instead for iteration. Regarding "unbuffered code," it just means the result of the code won't be written to the output/result. Though, any lines indented under it (`li item`) can.